# How to invoke .exe file of printer driver from a java application

Tags: java, printing

I am new to java programming. I am developing java application in which I am trying to invoke PLQ-30 printer driver exe which is installed in my PC but I am facing the issue, that exactly which .exe or .dll file I should use in my application.

After some research I found that the printer driver files are present in the following location C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository.

screenshot of printer driver file installed

[image]

I feel that highlighted file is the actual driver file but I am not sure.
How to identify which is the actual printer driver exe which gets invoked while working with printer?

Comment: Please write what you're trying to accomplish. Invoking exe file from java is easy enough, but invoking functions from dll is a completely different matter. Please give us more detail

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't need to speak to the driver of your printer directly as the operating system handels that for you normally.
A example of this from the [offical oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html):

```java
public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener {

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Now we perform our rendering */
        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

        /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setPrintable(this);
         boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
             try {
                  job.print();
             } catch (PrinterException ex) {
              /* The job did not successfully complete */
             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
 
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
        printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the code "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", null, new File("c:\\Windows\\"));" I Invoked Notepad exe from my application same way, now I want to invoke Printer Driver exe ( for PLQ 30) from the application, so I don't know which is that exe should be called. Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: you don't invoke the speaker driver if you want to print @meghanavardhana